# Json framing error

Tags: android, json

I have to frame a json like the following while making a json request:

```
{
  "method": "version",
  "data": {
    "username": "korea",
    "order_point_of_contact": {
      "shipment_version": "1",
      "testimonial_version": "3",
      "point_of_contact_version": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

I use the following code to frame it:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
JSONObject pointofContact = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

try {
     data.put("username", "korea");
     jsonObject.put("method", "version");
     jsonObject.put("data", data);
     jsonObject.put("order_point_of_contact", pointofContact);
     jsonObject.put("shipment_version", "1");
     jsonObject.put("testimonial_version", "3");
     jsonObject.put("point_of_contact_version", "2");

} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the problem is that it doesn't frame the desired json. What is the error that I'm committing?

Comment: you should use gson it's very easy

Comment: your json creation is completely wrong

Comment: you are missing to add your "order_point_of_contact" in to "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but looks like you're putting the values for `shipment_version`, `testimonial_version` and `point_of_contact_version` on the wrong JSONObject.

Judging by your desired JSON posted above, they should be added to `pointofContact`.

Your code should be doing something like this:

```
pointOfContact.put("shipment_version", "1");
pointOfContact.put("testimonial_version", "3");
pointOfContact.put("point_of_contact_version", "2");
data.put("username", "korea");
data.put("order_point_of_contact", pointofContact);
jsonObject.put("method", "version");
jsonObject.put("data", data);
```

The JSON should be nested correctly then.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below given code:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
JSONObject pointofContact = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                pointofContact .put("shipment_version", "1");
                pointofContact .put("testimonial_version", "3");
                pointofContact .put("point_of_contact_version", "2");
                data.put("username", "korea");
                data .put("order_point_of_contact", pointofContact);
                jsonObject.put("method", "version");
                jsonObject.put("data", data);



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json creation should be like this

```
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

                JSONObject pointofContact = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject .put("method", "version");
                try {
                    data.put("username", "korea");

                    pointofContact.put("shipment_version", "1");
                    pointofContact.put("testimonial_version", "3");
                    pointofContact.put("point_of_contact_version", "2");
                    data.put("order_point_of_contact", pointofContact);
                    jsonObject .put("data",data);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```